# False Positives with React Flow

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

Prior to me joining my current team, a colleague implemented React Flow.  In principle I like this idea because I fully appreciate the power of strongly typed languages.

However, it has become clear that React Flow is woefully lacking in sophistication and intelligence.  For example, in order to comply with one of its common "errors", we would have to remove constants in our Actions & Reducers and instead use literal strings.  This would be stepping backwards simply to comply with a tool that doesn't understand that its recommendations are worse than the approach used.

I'm thinking that others have come up across this situation.  In our case, we were planning on having Flow as a "gatekeeper" for whether code would get merged or not.  This will no longer work.  So how have you dealt with this conundrum?

UPDATE: As per @Alex Savin's comment below, here's a tangible example of Flow's "limitations":

Actions:

```
// @flow

import type { SystemMessage } from '../SessionContext';
// Note: 'ActionType' is just a string
import type { ActionType } from '../../redux/FlowTypes';

export const UPDATE_SESSION_PROP: ActionType = 'UPDATE_SESSION_PROP';
export const ADD_SYSTEM_MESSAGE: ActionType = 'ADD_SYSTEM_MESSAGE';
export const CLEAR_SYSTEM_MESSAGE: ActionType = 'CLEAR_SYSTEM_MESSSAGE';

type UpdateSessionAction = {type: typeof UPDATE_SESSION_PROP,
                            propName: string,
                            payload: string | number};

type AddSystemMessageAction = {type: typeof ADD_SYSTEM_MESSAGE,
                               payload: SystemMessage};

type ClearSystemMessageAction = {type: typeof CLEAR_SYSTEM_MESSAGE};                         

export type SessionAction =
     | UpdateSessionAction
     | AddSystemMessageAction
     | ClearSystemMessageAction;
```

Reducer:

```
// @flow

import type { SessionState } from '../SessionContext';
import type { SessionAction } from '../actions/Session';

import { UPDATE_SESSION_PROP, 
         ADD_SYSTEM_MESSAGE,
         CLEAR_SYSTEM_MESSAGE } from '../actions/Session';

export const sessionReducer = (state: SessionState, action: SessionAction) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_SESSION_PROP: {
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.propName]: action.payload
      };
    }

    case ADD_SYSTEM_MESSAGE: {
      return {
        ...state,
        systemMessage: action.payload
      }
    }

    case CLEAR_SYSTEM_MESSAGE: {
      return {
        ...state,
        systemMessage: {}
      }
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

Sample Dispatch call:

```
dispatchSession({type: ADD_SYSTEM_MESSAGE, payload: {status, message}});
```

These are the errors being displayed by Flow:

Actions:

> None

Reducer

> The `propName` of `action.propName`:
>
> Cannot get `action.propName` because property `propName` is missing in
>   `AddSystemMessageAction` [1].Flow(InferError) Session.js(11, 61): [1]
>   `AddSystemMessageAction` Cannot get `action.propName` because property
>   `propName` is missing in  `ClearSystemMessageAction`
>   [1].Flow(InferError) Session.js(11, 61): [1]
>   `ClearSystemMessageAction`
>
> The `payload` of both `action.payload` instances: ``` Cannot get
>   `action.payload` because property `payload` is missing in 
>   `ClearSystemMessageAction` [1].Flow(InferError) Session.js(11, 61):
>   [1] `ClearSystemMessageAction`

The sample Dispatch call:

> Could not decide which case to select, since  case 2 [1] may work but
>   if it doesn't  case 3 [2] looks promising too. To fix add a type
>   annotation  to `status` [3].Flow(InferError) Session.js(29, 8): [1]
>   case 2 Session.js(30, 8): [2] case 3 AddUsers.js(139, 62): [3] to
>   `status`

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code example on http://flow.org/try that would reproduce the problem with the constants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not type action types properly? Like [this](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBTAHgBzgJwBcwBjOAOwGdiBVABQBEBBAFQFEB9AZTa64EkA8gDkOdAEqC6ALjAByes3bdeAkWMl05YALzzFrTjz5DREqXIDcmXAWJkqxJgwbcAml3YBZDl9VMAcTZZOWdXLg9vX38g7T1Ql3dPNh8-PkC2Kxs8IlIKajAAYQAZNiZxJKi0rgyQkrKKiOTU1RrY3Xl68sqU6L42zOtUQgBPHAwwGhwAEwBDQgwuDEpKAEsKJhJCdfIOgG9R8dlDjDgoScZDFRN1czoAGlQwZ5fXt-ePnHw4HGFZgFsMLJqPhVuQAOaPD7QmGvHCzEbwWbTYGEUEQsAAHzA5AArv8AEYYfAAXyGJzATGm0y4I2oGH+XmWlFm4Iwm22FH2J2OY1O5zCPRa6SCUNh4ph8MRcGRsj2YEBK1ZQPkILB4O0JLJ6AphRgGFm+Fp9MZzOVHJ23L5vPGZyKpW6TSqMTYZIl7vQ2ByxApSxWOwtXJ0T1e2KmcwWfrWGy2OxDL2xVJpdIWpqVbMD5Hjz2xeoNRpTDKZ6fZsYoQwcBUozJ24gw01xJGJHQAFNR5ir5QBtADWGBGqPR4IAuoP1VicfiifgwCT7mBZmXyLIowGlwBKXQAPjAexDlAQq0IJAAFmAW4vOeQAHQnTd714kWbVi5KIyqUwaKRy7PPfAYQhcXwXYHw+a9wPbBYxXeLtLx2a8vh+P5AVHBclwQhEkWmX9Z2sV4SXQR9nwmQUnV6apal3HD-0A4CqOhcDr0gjBoLeShCzTFk2VkOCKAw6VkRwgj8MIl4nxfLpGkiciXR-d4aKAkCcOeRjmNY152JNYsuM7YS3j054COzaYMCgWZcRgQg5LeBS6OYvCXj0giSSAA)

```
export const UPDATE_SESSION_PROP: 'UPDATE_SESSION_PROP' = 'UPDATE_SESSION_PROP';
```

I understand that it's a bit repetitive, but you can try instruments like keymirrror to avoid repetition

Comment: You use the word "properly" but I don't believe there is anything "improper" with the way I've done it.  I fully realize that your approach gets around the limitation of Flow typing but what Computer Science professor would say that this syntax you've used makes any sense?

Comment: Well, you use an instrument. This instrument has a concept of literal types. You can use the instrument properly. Of course, you can just stop using it.

Comment: TypeScript has the same concept http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types So I think there’s nothing wrong with the concept from the CS point of view

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, @Alex Savin.  My apologies if I'm coming across with a negative tone.  I'm just frustrated with Flow.

Comment: Don’t worry. 
I think you will be even more frustrated if you will continue to use it. Literal types at least a documented feature and it works as expected. 

The sad truth is:

1. Flow has bugs
2. TypeScript has bugs
3. It’s still better to type (IMHO)

Comment: Thought you'd like to know that upon reflection, I've decided to follow the approach you outlined @ 9:39am on October 11th.  I find the syntax weird but I understand what's going on and the typing errors disappear which is the ultimate goal.  Thank you, sir!